# Whats the purpose of the "delete-this" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Whats the purpose of the "delete-this" tag in SQA?

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete-this

Is it related to deleting some method or row or is it about flagging something for deletion?

Currently there is only one question with this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't serve a purpose.

It was placed there by a high rep user as to send a message to the moderators to delete it. If something should be deleted, I recommend using a flag instead.

I've taken care of the offending question, and the tag will go away on its own.